# Configure fix() and edit() to open in Notepad++ from R/RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio, rgui

When I do this in RStudio or RGUI:

```
fix(SomeFunction)
```

(or using `edit()`) I can see the function's code in Notepad. Is there any way that I could change this so that the code preview opens in Notepad++ rather than plain old Notepad? And similarly, is there anyway that I could force `View(SomeDataFrame)` to open up in Excel?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`fix` and `edit` functions invoke the editor defined in the `"editor"` argument.
By default, that argument is set to `getOption('editor')` as shown in the [edit function documentation](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/utils/html/edit.html).

Therefore, you can either pass the notepad++ path as function argument, i.e. :

```
path <- "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Notepad++\\Notepad++.exe"
fix(somefunction,editor=path)
```

or set notepad++ as default editor by changin R options for the current session i.e. :

```
path <- "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Notepad++\\Notepad++.exe"

options(editor=path)

# from now on, all calls to fix and edit will open notepad++ as default editor...
fix(somefunction)
```

**N.B.**

If you want to set the new option as the default for all the next sessions, you should edit `Rprofile.site` script in `RHome\etc` path as explained [here](http://www.statmethods.net/interface/customizing.html).

Comment: If you're on a computer with multiple R users it would be better to configure .Rprofile instead of .Rprofile.site.

Answer (score 5):

You could try something like [this](http://r-trek.blogspot.com/2012/10/viewing-large-dataframes-in-rstudio.html) to create a temporary .csv and open in Excel.

Comment: Thanks that's perfect. Unfortunately I can only mark one answer as accepted so I can only give you a measly +1.

Comment: Obsolete now that RStudio views full datasets