# Error in .External2 when using edit() function from RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

When I execute the `edit()` function in RStudio I am receiving the following error message.

```
Error in .External2(C_edit, name, file, title, editor) : problem with running editor vi
```

When I execute `R` directly from a terminal and run the `edit()` function it opens vi.  I'm not sure why this is happening rather than opening the `R Data Editor`

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13990631/configure-fix-and-edit-to-open-in-notepad-from-r-rstudio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`edit()` uses the default system editor by default on non-windows systems, yours seem to be vi and incorrectly configured.

Try:

`edit(x, editor="internal")`

for the RStudio one.